# Stratum + MPOS pool question

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools, litecoin, altcoin

This is the first pool I have configured so forgive my n00bness.
https://github.com/MPOS/php-mpos/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide
I completed the guide and everything appears to fire up correctly though when a client connects, he only receives rejections.

What step am I missing?
I have a suspicion that being on a 'test network' vs the Litecoin network via the 'how to' is a little suspicious, but I am new to the software and not sure how it works yet.

```
http://bpaste.net/show/z0oOnziLKekXmuW7pEKy/

I have no firewall

http://bpaste.net/show/jssOUYVrMP3ckdaZomfq/


asterisk1 home # ./minerd -o stratum+tcp://domain.com:19334 -O my.my:pass -t 1
[2014-01-26 19:42:40] Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://digitaldriller.com:19334
[2014-01-26 19:42:40] 1 miner threads started, using 'scrypt' algorithm.
[2014-01-26 19:42:40] stratum_recv_line failed
[2014-01-26 19:42:40] ...retry after 30 seconds
^C
asterisk1 home # ./minerd -o stratum+tcp://domain.com:3333 -O my.my:pass -t 1
[2014-01-26 19:43:21] Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://digitaldriller.com:3333
[2014-01-26 19:43:21] 1 miner threads started, using 'scrypt' algorithm.
[2014-01-26 19:43:21] Stratum connection failed: Failed connect to digitaldriller.com:3333; Connection refused
[2014-01-26 19:43:21] ...retry after 30 seconds

or at best  http://i.imgur.com/xEl0qVs.png
```

Comment: I have the same problem when starting stratum + mpos. Everything seems to look fine and I also installed + compiled the stratum stuff as explained above.
But when trying to connect using minerd I always receive "Stratum connection failed: Failed to connect to.... port 3333: Connection refused". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Did you do these steps to make sure stratum had the correct stuff compiled?

> sudo apt-get install python-twisted python-mysqldb python-dev python-setuptools python-memcache python-simplejson
>   easy_install -U distribute
>   git clone http://github.com/Tydus/litecoin_scrypt.git
>   git clone http://github.com/ahmedbodi/stratum-mining.git
>   git clone http://github.com/ahmedbodi/stratum.git
>   cd stratum-mining
>   git submodule init
>   git submodule update
>   cd externals/litecoin_scrypt
>   sudo python setup.py install
>   cd ~
>   cd stratum-mining/externals/stratum
>   sudo python setup.py install

Comment: I added some linebreaks there, and I assumed that you wanted those double asterisks to be asterisks, so I escaped them. If that wasn't your intention please feel free to edit.

Comment: no sorry, I should have been more clear, was a bit rushed before.... the **github** should be changed to  github.com  I put that in as I am a new member and am limited to number of URL's in single post...

Comment: Ahh. I hope this is how you meant it. :)